# ASP.net E-Commerce Catalog Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, photoshop

I have designed a template in Photoshop and I was wondering how I can implement the boxes that I designed into Visual Studio to display the products in Grid View, similar to those we usually see in E-commerce sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're many choices in asp.net controls: for the easier way you can use DataGrid or GridView controls, for a more pro way you can use Repeater to generate html of table/tr/td, the most flexable way, you can directly use for loop to show your data.

The core is just table/tr/td elements, even with DataGrid or GridView.

Comment: Can the DataGrid or GridView be customized to use the skin that I designed on Photoshop?

Comment: depends on what the Photoshop design looks like.  You can always use a Repeater control which will give you more control over the HTML layout

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations guys. My mockup design looks as follows, http://i53.tinypic.com/1z5qdeq.jpg and I would like to display the products individually with product image, name, price in each box. I believe they call this the multicolumn grid. Would ListVIew be better for this purpose?

Comment: From looking at the mockup, I'd go with the repeater and use some custom HTML to create the look that is needed.